# Profile cards and Pattern cards

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, personalization, experience-profile

As I am working on profile cards and pattern cards, So would like to get information about below scenario.

> What is the use of Profile's Key field while creating profile? And how sitecore uses them(If any explanation would be great) ?

Basically, Type field has three values(Sum, Average and Percentage)

> What happens when we prefer to go with Sum instead Percentage? How it works internally?

Given below example

I have two pages (General-Account, Standard-Account) and created following profile

**Custom**(Profile)

- General
- Standard

**Profile cards**

- General(Given 2 points per visit)
- Standard(Given 2 points per visit)

**Pattern cards**

- General - Given 4(General) - 0(Standard) point to be accumulated.
- Standard - Given 2(General) - 4(Standard) point to be accumulated.

If I visit a General page in explore window from experience editor then user has matched to General pattern. In order to match the pattern as General, 
 User should be visiting General page two times(As per my understanding about given points to **General pattern**)

If visitor view General-Account for one time and Standard-Account for two times So user should be matched with 2nd pattern (**Standarda**).Is it how it works?

> How points would be considered while matching the pattern?

Any inputs and explanations would be really helpful.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kumari,

I think you're asking how Sitecore calculates profile value, and how it's displayed when the profile uses the **sum** type.  It really is a sum; meaning it's additive.

Based on the way the question is phrased, I wonder if you may not be clear on the difference between profiles, profile keys, profile cards and pattern cards.

#### Profile

A profile is a category that you set-up to track a visitors behavior.  In your case, the profile is 'Custom'. It is the main organizational unit of this category you are "tracking" on. As an example you could have a profile of Athletics that would help clasify the content by what types of athletics it pertains to. You could also have a profile called User Journey, that could help classify how deep into a category they are (beginner vs advanced knowledge),

#### Profile Key

A profile key is an attribute of the profile.  In your case, the profile keys for 'Custom' are 'General' and 'Standard'. A profile key is pie slice of your Profile. If we had a profile called Athletics, the profile keys could be:

- Running
- Swimming
- Jumping
- Throwing

#### Profile Card

A profile card is a predefined set of profile keys and values. So instead of assigning keys and values to each piece of content, you can predefine several off them and just assign profile cards to content. Examples of profile cards is:

- Basketball

  - Running [4]
  - Swimming [0]
  - Jumping [9]
  - Throwing [4]
- Baseball

  - Running [8]
  - Swimming [0]
  - Jumping [2]
  - Throwing [9]
- Diving

  - Running [2]
  - Swimming [10]
  - Jumping [2]
  - Throwing [0]

#### Pattern Card

A pattern card is an indicator of the visitor's relationship with the content. The profile keys that are set on the pages the user visits and are added up and calculated. So based on their browsing behavior, what do they look like they're interested in. In your case, if we created pattern cards for 'General' and 'Standard', that each had 4 points, the visitor would trigger those pattern cards when they accumulated 4 points of value.

#### Example

Let's say 'John' visited 2 pages that are tagged 'General' and one page that's tagged 'Standard'.  He'd have 4 'Custom' profile points for 'General' and he'd earn the pattern card of 'General'.  He'd also have 2 'Custom' profile points for 'Standard' and would not have enough value to earn that pattern card match.

Comment: thankyou for your response and clear explanation.